# Init class deriving from protocol

Tags: swift

I've got a class deriving from a simple protocol. It looks like this:

```
protocol Interface {
    func f() -> Void;
}
class TestInterface : Interface {
    var arr: [Int] = [];
    func f() {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't create this class as Swift has it has no initializers (although the default one would blatantly suffice).

However, the more serious problem is trying to define the initializer. Initially I tried to define an empty initializer. Swift told me that this was illegal because I did not call the super initializer (even though it's a protocol...). Fine, I thought. I called `super.init()`. Swift then told me this was illegal because the base is a protocol and not a class, so it has no `init` function. So I can't define an init function because I must call a nonexistent init function inside my own init function. And the normal init function is randomly unavailable for no good reason.

How the hell can I create an instance of my super simple class?

Comment: I copied what you posted into a 1.2 playground and it gave me no problems.  Are you using Swift 2 or is this specific to a built app?

Comment: Show what you have tried, also those semicolons hurt my eyes

Comment: Your code (plus an empty initializer `init() { }`) compiles without problems with Swift 1.2 and Swift 2 beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a totally unrelated issue. The protocol actually used to be a class. For an unrelated reason, the module that this class was imported from crashed the Swift compiler, and corrupted the metadata. So when Swift came to read the metadata for this class/protocol, it was inconsistent and confused the compiler.

As soon as I resolved the issue with the source module (and actually noticed it, thanks crappy XCode error reporting) this was no longer an issue for me.